# Espeak not working with jessie

Tags: raspbian-jessie

I have a problem getting espeak to work with Raspbian Jessie. I have espeak working on wheezy and other audio programs are working on Jessie but espeak and Jessie are not working together.

Let's start with what is working. I have a RPi with Wheezy installed and using the Adafruit Audio Adapter (Part ID 1475). I installed espeak with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install espeak
```

after installing espeak I could type:

```
espeak "Hello world"
```

and the espeak program would say "Hello world" through the speaker connected to the audio adapter. In addition to the audio I would receive a bunch of error messages in the terminal (normal, I know how to remove the error messages).

I started a project with an official RPi touchscreen and downloaded the most current NOOBs. I installed my audio adapter and tested it with Sonic Pi by typing:

```
speaker-test -c2
```

I get the wight noise from the speaker. I then installed espeak on the Jessie Pi by using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install espeak
```

I then entered the following command in to the terminal:

```
espeak "Hello world"
```

I got the same errors on the Jessie Pi as I do with the Wheezy Pi but the Jessie Pi did not talk. Thinking I lost connection or something I tested it all out again with:

```
speaker-test -c2
```

and got white noise. I then tested out Sonic Pi with the following command:

```
Play 70
```

The Jessie Pi played the corresponding note. I was at a loss and decided it was something else I installed along the way, so I reformatted my SD card and did a fresh install of Jessie. This time I had it plugged into the HDMI TV my Wheezy Pi is plugged into and only installed espeak by using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install espeak
```

I then tried the command:

```
espeak "Hello world"
```

and nothing came from the speakers on my HDMI TV. The next step I tried was to install only the audio adapter and test everything out. Following the guide on the Adafruit website to install the audio adapter and had nothing else on the Jessie Pi but espeak and the adapter. I was able to get a note to play through the speaker connected to the audio adapter by typing in Sonic Pi:

```
Play 70
```

I was also able to get white noise through the speaker connected to the audio adapter by typing:

```
speaker-test -c2
```

I then tested espeak with:

```
espeak "Hello world"
```

I got a the regular error messages but no talking. I do not know what I am missing to get espeak working on Jessie.

Robb

Comment: I use `espeak` with Jessie all the time, so there is no reason it shouldn't work for you. Unfortunately, your question contains no helpful information other than "it doesn't work." Please include any errors you are getting, how you installed it, how you've been using it, and what you have tried to fix it.